# PowerShell filer out invalid AD users using -filte {SamAccountName -eq $_} but with regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to filter AD for user names based on computer names which contain the user name, like `XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ` (BLOGGSJ`enter code here` is the user name in this example)

In order to extract the user name, I use this method:

```
"XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ" | %{($_ -split '\d+')[-1]}
```

The output is BLOGGSJ

However, I need to filter many computer names like this, a small percentage of which have invalid usernames in the machine name like "XXXXXX01RUBBISH"

In order to stop the inevitable errors from appearing I am trying to use the `-filter {SamAccountName $_}` method which works like this:

```
"BLOGGSJ", "RUBBISH" | % {Get-ADUser -Server domain.com -Filter{SamAccountName -eq $_ }} | select Name
```

But not when I attempt to do this, which is what I want to do:

```
“XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ”, “XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ” | % {Get-ADUser -Server domain.com -Filter{SamAccountName -eq "'($_ -split '\d+')[-1]'"}} | select Name

……or various permutations of that. So I am struggling with the syntax I think.
```

I know I can do this instead:

```
"XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ","XXXXXX01RUBBISH" | %{($_ -split '\d+')[-1]} | %{Get-ADUser -Server domain.com -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $_ }} | Select Name
```

but there is something else happening further down the pipe that requires me to do it in the way shown above.

Any help please.

Comment: the filter parameter for the AD cmdlets IS NOT a scriptblock. it is a `[string]`. even tho many docs show a scriptblock ... it IS NOT a scriptblock - it is a string. you cannot use any of the regex commands in that filter string. you will need to do your advanced filtering after you get your result back from the AD call. i suggest you grab them all - with only the minimum properties - and do your filtering on that. it will reduce the laod on your servers AND likely run faster.

Comment: the following shows the valid operators for an AD filter >>> Demystifying Active Directory and LDAP Filters in PowerShell — https://adamtheautomator.com/active-directory-filter-powershell/

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Especially because you say *something else is happening further down*, I would suggest not trying to do all in a one-line code.

This should get you on your way:

```
"XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ","XXXXXX01RUBBISH" | ForEach-Object {
    $name = ($_ -split '\d+')[-1]
    $user = Get-ADUser -Server domain.com -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # a user with that SamAccountName was found
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName   = $_
            SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
            UserName       = $user.Name
        }
    }
    else {
        # user not found
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName   = $_
            SamAccountName = $name
            UserName       = "User Not found in AD"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ComputerName    SamAccountName UserName            
------------    -------------- --------            
XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ bloggsj        Joe Bloggs          
XXXXXX01RUBBISH RUBBISH        User Not found in AD
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, I know how to do custom objects and have already written a script very similar to that. I was ultimately trying to create a one-liner to get Name, Office and Computer, and this works perfectly except I cannot stop the errors on invalid user names:  "XXXXXX01BLOGGSJ", "XXXXXX01RUBBISH" | % {Get-ADUser -Server domain.com -id($_ -split '\d+')[-1] -Properties * | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Computer -Value $_ -f -PassThru} | Select Name, Office, Computer

Comment: @IanB - one liners tend to be slow, difficult to debug, and difficult to pin down just what is what. they otta be used primarily when you need them [to save RAM at the expense of speed], OR for short pipelines, OR at the command line.